# Steam and Electricity

Tags: electricity

If an electrical  conduit with sufficient voltage were cut and lay naked inside a chamber of steam, would an electrical arc occur?  As a secondary question, if the steam were subject to a stabilized pressure wave, in what manner, if any, would an arc occur?

Comment: You can make an arc occur through any substance if the voltage is high enough.  What is a stabilized pressure wave?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvx3j.png

Comment: So you're asking if a standing acoustic wave effects conductivity then it would only in a way that in the areas where the water or other ions are denser you'd get better ionization or possibility for spark.  Do you have something specific in mind because this question is not very clear?

Comment: Would the arc of electricity follow the standing wave of the steam versus randomly shooting out in different directions.  Like electricity would flow in a wire.

Comment: If you are talking about a generic sauna as your test structure, then random is your answer.  Steam is a poor conductor.  Plasma stability is difficult to achieve due to many non-linear issues. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_stability‎

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you edited the question from a sauna to what I assume is a insulated test chamber.  Steam would have very little change in the voltage required to getting a spark.  You would also need more than just a bare wire, you would need a grounding plate inside your chamber.  The voltage would primarily be a function of the air gap separating your wire and your ground.  Any ionized gases would assist in lowering that voltage threshold, whereas water vapor would probably not change the conductivity much at all.

For your second question, steam in an acoustic standing wave probably wouldn't have a noticeable effect.  You really need a gas that can conduct.  In plasma physics this is called an ion pressure wave.  These waves are used to excite and conduct the plasma usually between two electric plates like your wire and ground.

From the comments I think you want the current to flow along the direction of the wave like a wire, but it actually would flow perpendicular to it.  This is where the gas gets compressed increasing the amount of free electrons available for conduction.

Comment: Could you possibly answer my question on the current and magnetic fields on a triple braided copper wire.  The question is posted.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106003/what-is-the-effect-on-current-and-magnetic-fields